# Can we find some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n k! \equiv m $ mod $n$ for all $n$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to answer wether if it is possible to find a positive integer $m$ such that for all integers $n \geq 2$, $\sum_{k=1}^n k! \equiv m $ mod $n$. I am quite confused with this question, because I am not sure what it means to "satisfy infinitely many congruences".

Thanks in advance.

(Edit)
I have solved the systems for some n:

n=2 $\Rightarrow$ m=1

n=3 $\Rightarrow$ m=3

n=4 $\Rightarrow$ m=9

n=5 $\Rightarrow$ m=33

n=6 $\Rightarrow$ m=33

n=7 $\Rightarrow$ m=33

n=8 $\Rightarrow$ m=33

n=9 $\Rightarrow$ m=873

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: Putting "some m" then statement then "for all n" is very ambiguous.  Please put all of your quantifiers either at the start or all at the end of the statement.

Comment: @DanielV I have eddited the question.

Comment: Are you confused what a congruence is, or how there are infinitely many of them, or what it means to satisfy an equation?

Comment: @lulu I have been able to solve the congruences when I consider finitely many of them. But I have no idea about what to say when I consider infinitely many of them.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your efforts.  The sequence of values $\pmod n$ seems relevant.

Comment: @DanielV I am not sure if a number can satisfy infinitely many different congruence relations.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  A priori, there's no reason why this sum might not, say, vanish $\pmod n$ for all $n$.  This is one reason why examples are so important (though no finite list of examples is going to settle the point).

Comment: @Andarrkor Then solve the problem for $2 \le n \le 5$

Comment: @lulu there you have it. I have solved the system for $2 \leq n \leq 9$.

Comment: What is the value of the expression for $n=2$? For $n=3$? If these are not the same, then the answer to your question is 'No'

Comment: @DanielV I have edited the post with my results.

Comment: @KeithBackman The number of equations and the remainder depends on $n$. I do not know it this makes sense at all, that is why I am asking here.

Comment: Why write, e.g., $5$ for the case of $n=4$?  Isn't it more natural to write the least non-negative residue?